# More than one, What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You see that I am more than one,
Without me you cannot have won.
Puzzle out how much I have done.

Hiding in measures you'll find me,
Part of power that helps you see.
In kids transportation I'll be.

Shapes and words, I am all around.
At the beginning I'm often found.
Tell me, to what number am I bound?

Hint 1:

> There is a clue hidden within the entire riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> "tri"? (three, tree, try etc)

You see that I am more than one,

> because 3>1

Without me you cannot have won.

> could be TRIumph or you can't win without TRYing

Puzzle out how much I have done.

> You've done a great conTRIbution?

Hiding in measures you'll find me,

> As number three and in trigonometry. Could be musical reference too

Part of power that helps you see.

> Lots of options here like 3D or isomeTRIc vision for example. Also elecTRIcity like others have pointed out.

In kids transportation I'll be.

> Tricycles

Shapes and words, I am all around.

> Triangles and it's pretty common in english words

At the beginning I'm often found.

> Common prefix. Songs also start with "one two three..."

Tell me, to what number am I bound?

> Obviously number three.

Comment: You've got it! The only line you don't have is measures -> me**tri**c.

Answer (score 4):

First guess:

> The letter O/number 0

You see that I am more than one,

> The word one has 2 additional letters

Without me you cannot have won.

> Similarly you can't spell the word without the letter o

Puzzle out how much I have done.

> TBD

Hiding in measures you'll find me,

> This I took as a whole note, which takes up a full measure in music

Part of power that helps you see.

> An [ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm) is a measure of resistance

In kids transportation I'll be.

> A wheel is a circular object that is needed on school buses

Shapes and words, I am all around.

> Physically a round letter/number

At the beginning I'm often found.

> Many fields 0 index which means they count from 0 onwards

Answer (score 3):

Just a shot:

> 3?

You see that I am more than one

> 3 is clearly more than one

Without me you cannot have won.

> not entirely sure here

Puzzle out how much I have done

> Still not sure

Hiding in measures you'll find me,

> Musical reference. there are measures involving counts of 3.

Part of power that helps you see.

> Three phase power is crucial to generating and transferring electricity, providing light

In kids transportation I'll be.

> Reference to tricycles.

Shapes and words, I am all around

> Triangles and 3 letter/syllable words are common

The hint refers to:

> There are 3 stanzas of 3 lines each

Comment: Very very close, but not quite. The answer is not 3. You have a couple of the clues though.

Comment: @AggieKidd is it number 11(binary for 3)? but I don't have any other clues

Comment: Not quite, but thinking along the right track. Think of other "not three" items.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> I/eye

You see that I am more than one,

> I is simialr to 1 and can be confused with each other, We generally have more than one eye.

Without me you cannot have won.

> Needed my eyes to read this

Puzzle out how much I have done.  - not Sure

Hiding in measures you'll find me,

> Often find a | in measures. Again similar to the letter I

Part of power that helps you see.

> Need eyes to see

In kids transportation I'll be.

> The I and bicycle

Shapes and words, I am all around.

> The letter I is every where.

At the beginning I'm often found.

> Sentences often begin with I

Tell me, to what number am I bound?

> 1 due to the similar shape

Comment: +1 for a good attempt and some good thoughts, but if it is tied to one, then it isn't more than one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Vowels

You see that I am more than one

> Sure, a-e-i-o-u

Without me you cannot have won.

> You cannot have the word 'won' without the letter 'o'

Puzzle out how much I have done.

Hiding in measures you'll find me,

> e-a-u-e

Part of power that helps you see.

> e's in 'eye'

In kids transportation I'll be.

> 'u' in 'bus' or 'school bus'

Shapes and words, I am all around.

> Found in all shapes and words!

At the beginning I'm often found.

> I and A

Tell me, to what number am I bound?

> Not sure about this one. I guess the number which contains all the 5 vowels. It should be in thousands (as only thousand has an 'a')

Comment: A good attempt, but no. +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> 2?

You see that I am more than one,
Without me you cannot have won.
Puzzle out how much I have done.

> Two is more than one, without someone being second there is no winner.

Hiding in measures you'll find me,
Part of power that helps you see.
In kids transportation I'll be.

> Well, 2 can be in measures of course, and the "most common" power ist a power of 2. I am not sure about kids transportation, but I might be missing a common name for it as english is not my native language.

Shapes and words, I am all around.
At the beginning I'm often found.
Tell me, to what number am I bound?

> There are lots of shapes/geometries based on 2, as well as words using it (two-faced and so on. Humans like to compare 2 things.) So, are you bound to 2?

Comment: +1 for a good attempt, but no. There are a couple of items that two doesn't address.

Answer (score 1):

You are bound to :

> 100

And

> You is "Rest"

Here's why

You see that I am more than one,

> There is multiple type of musical rest (full, half etc...)

Without me you cannot have won.

> Without rest, you are not at full potential to compete ? OR can't complete (win) a music going off by one rest will break the melodies

Puzzle out how much I have done.

> During rest, we dream. Puzzle out mean "figuring out what the dream mean"

Hiding in measures you'll find me,

> A rest can be found in musical sheet

Part of power that helps you see.

> Not sure, may referre to a rest in physics. See Newton's firts law of motion

In kids transportation I'll be.

> Kids often sleep during long period of transportation

Shapes and words, I am all around.

> No matter langage and living races, everyone rest.

At the beginning I'm often found.

> First thing you do on your day is waking up (from rest)

Tell me, to what number am I bound?

> Rest is bound to 100 (counting 100 sheeps to go to sleep)

Comment: +1 for a good try, but no. Missing a few items here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> III (Roman for 3)

Taking into account @Eagle0100 's answer, and OP's hints

Hint:

> In kids transportation **I'll** be.

I haven't really solved all the clues by myself, so not sure if I should include them here, but pretty sure that is the answer

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is not the answer. Check Toteemi's answer.